# Log4j properties to non-admin rights needed file in Windows

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, permissions, log4j

I'm using log4j for my logging and I have two `log4j.properties` files, one for logging to stdout (to develop) and another to log to a file (production).

In this case, the user will run the program on Windows 7 x86 without administrator rights, so I guess that the logging operation can't be done because my log file is in the installation folder (`C:\Program Files\...`).

The first solution that I thought of was to have the log file in the user folder (`C:\User\%Name%`). I know that I can get that folder programmatically with:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

but how can I get that property in a Java `.properties` file, in this case `log4j.properties`?

Then I thought about having a `templatelog4j.properties` with an area marked to replace with the user folder path, but I want to avoid that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, I found the answer:

You can use every VM property inside a `.properties` file (at least `log4j.properties`) using `${NAME}`. [Here's an example](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html#disk).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you default the logging location to a place that you *know* will be accessible, and allow the user to put it somewhere else if they wish?

Comment: It's easy that way, the log file isn't for the user, it's for crash/bug reports, so the user shouldn't need to know that a log file exists (unless he wants to see it)